# How to debug a javascript undefined error in third party code.

Tags: javascript

So I am using tinyMce in my app but I am getting a JavaScript error that I can't really seem to figure out how to debug. The error is "TypeError: P is undefined" - I can see that from FireBug but I have no idea how to get more / better information?

I tried turning on "break on all errors" but that just shows me the minimized JS file and I can't even see a variable named "P" in there so I am guessing I am barking up the wrong tree. The whole thing works fine except when I click save.

*shrug* I am just stuck at the moment. Here is my complete code. you can see I tried removing all the plugins thinking that might be it but no dice.

Obviously the problem I need to solve is why that is happening - the better solution would be how to figure out what is actually causing it so when something like this happens again I can figure it out myself.

Thanks - see the complete code below.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                script_url: '/Scripts/TinyMCE/tiny_mce.js',
                theme: "advanced",
                plugins: "save",
                theme_advanced_buttons1: "save",
//                plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
//                theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,print,|,iespell",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
                save_enablewhendirty: true,
                encoding: "xml",
                theme_advanced_resizing: true,
                mode: "textareas",
                save_onsavecallback: "ajaxSave",
                setup: function(ed) {
                    ed.onSaveContent.add(function(i, o) {
                        o.content = o.content.replace( /&#39/g , "&apos");
                    });
                }
            });

            function ajaxSave() {
                alert("ajaxSave called.");
            }

        });

    </script>
    <% Html.BeginForm("Index", "DisabilityReport", FormMethod.Post); %>  
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <%= Html.ModelData() %>
    <textarea name="documentContent" class="tinymce" cols="90" rows="60"></textarea>
    <% Html.EndForm();%>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Without the source its pretty difficult, I'd say. You could always use a beautifier (http://jsbeautifier.org/) to un-minify, but that is more of a workaround of course.

Comment: Firebug will tell you on which line (and in which JS file) the error is occurring. That will help narrow down where the error is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about Firebug, but if you're working in Chrome, the Chrome dev tools can expand compressed JS, making it easier to track down these errors. See the brackets button below:

[image]

Comment: so I used chrome and that does help a little but it tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined" - I looked at the code that it spit out and there is no apply... Uhg.

Comment: `apply` is a method of every function in JavaScript but it seems that your variable is not a function but undefined.

Comment: With a little bit of digging I found that you can load the tiny_mce_src.js version and then you don't get the minified files but I am marking this as the answer because Chrome had such a nice debugger I found the error easily. Go look at the code! Where is the definitation of ajaxSave? Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a little plugin called JS Deminifier, which can deminify code on the fly. The only downside is it can sometimes create bugs in the process.

It's nice to get an idea of what you're looking for, but don't rely on it fully.